# Aplication multi Company

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application, which I only have configured for one company, I need to change it, so that it accepts multiple companies, as follows:
When you create a company, create the independent db for that company and in turn the user, later when that user with that company_id authenticates, connect to that previously created database.

def create
@datos_empresa = DatosEmpresa.new(datos_empresa_params)

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @datos_empresa.save
    client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => 'localhost', :username=>"*****", :password=> "*********")
    nombre_db = 'name_company'+@datos_empresa.nombre
    client.query("CREATE DATABASE #{nombre_db.downcase}")

    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(client)

    format.html { redirect_to @datos_empresa, notice: 'Datos empresa was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @datos_empresa }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @datos_empresa.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: were you research about multitenant ?

Comment: conn_config = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
conn_config[:database] = new_database
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection conn_config

Answer (score -1):

The best way I found of doing this on my application was using the [ros-apartment](https://github.com/rails-on-services/apartment) gem, it handles all the DB creation, migrations (bet you forgot that one), seeds and switching.